# boto3 s3.download_file is hanging in docker

Tags: python, docker, boto3

The download of the file requested by boto3 s3.download_file is hanging. Why is that?

Our build suddenly broke between the 9th and 10th September 2019, but we didn't change anything.

We're using a dockerized environment and we already have some threading going on besides the boto3 s3.download_file.

Answer (score 3):

The fix for us was to disable threading:

```
s3.download_file(Bucket=amazon_s3_bucket, Key=amazon_s3_path, Filename=filepath, Config=boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig(use_threads=False))
```